# SharePoint - list that cointains all items from one list and others

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

Is it possible in SharePoint 2010 to create a list that contains all the elements from a list and other items and keep both in sync?

I mean, let's say I have 2 lists and both have the same structure:

```
List A     List B
elem 1     elem 1
elem 2     elem 2
           elem 23
```

My goal is to have every element of list A in list B. That means that if I add an element in List A it should copied/inserted in List B

```
List A     List B
elem 1     elem 1
elem 2     elem 2
elem 4     elem 4
           elem 23
```

Comment: [This](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130182/sync-two-sharepoint-lists) might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Simplest way is to create OOTB designer workflow in list A which will trigger on Item adding event and copy the item to List B.
2. If you have coding background then you can try using event receiver option too.
3. If we are talking about very large no of data being copied from list A to B then go for Timer job.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a very beginner with SharePoint and I didn't know anything about SharePoint workflows.